# Python extract from XML keep the same schema

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, split

I have an XML with the following schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ROOT>
<facturic id_user="18446195"><artfacturic/></facturic>
<facturic id_user="18446195"><artfacturic/></facturic>
<facturic id_user="34259554"><artfacturic/></facturic>
</ROOT>
```

They have much more attributes than id_user but only that one is relevant, because i need to split the xml file into separate files where there are duplicate ids.

I managed to find the duplicates using the code below:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree
dom = ElementTree.parse(fullpath)
findNode = 'facturic'
findAttr = 'id_user'
childNodes = dom.findall(findNode)
userIdDict = dict()     #student={'name':'john','age':23}
duplicateUserId = dict()

#GET UNIQUE USER ID AND COUNT
for c in childNodes:
    userId = c.attrib.get(findAttr)  #gets attributes
    #print(nrFact)

    if userId not in userIdDict:
        userIdDict[userId] = 1
    else:
        userIdDict[userId] = userIdDict[userId] + 1

# print(userIdDict)
for userId in userIdDict:
    userIdCount = userIdDict[userId]
    if userIdCount > 1:
        duplicateUserId[userId]=userIdCount
```

Can you guys give me an ideea how to create new xml files containing only nodes with duplicates, but using the same schema as the initial file? 
It should be something like create new xml file for each duplicate node, or ideally, let's say the maximum number of duplicate user id's is 4, create just 4 files, but each file should only contain unique id's with all other initial attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this: use a [`defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collect nodes per a single `id_user` value. Then, post-process the resulting dictionary, writing duplicates to a separate file. Using `lxml.etree`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

facturics = defaultdict(list)

for node in tree.xpath(".//facturic"):
    facturics[node.attrib["id_user"]].append(node)

for user_id, nodes in facturics.items():
    if len(nodes) > 1:  # save duplicates
        with open("{user_id}.xml".format(user_id=user_id), "w") as output_file:
            root = etree.Element("ROOT")
            for node in nodes:
                root.append(node)
            etree.ElementTree(root).write(output_file, pretty_print=True)
```

After running this code, there would be a new file called `18446195.xml` generated in the current directory with the following content:

```
<ROOT>
    <facturic id_user="18446195"><artfacturic/></facturic>
    <facturic id_user="18446195"><artfacturic/></facturic>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML such as keeping nodes with duplicate attributes. Python's third-party module, `lxml`, can run XSLT 1.0 scripts. The beauty too is XSLT is portable to other languages/software and does not need Python to run it!

Specifically, below uses the [Muenchenian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) to index the document with `xsl:key` for each distinct *@id_user*. Then the template match retrieves only those with counts greater than 1.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="idkey" match="facturic" use="@id_user" />

  <xsl:template match="/ROOT">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="facturic"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="facturic[count(key('idkey', @id_user)) > 1]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*"/>    
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(no `for` loop or `if` logic)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
doc = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER AND RUN
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    
result = transform(doc)

# PRINT TO CONSOLE
print(result)

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>
  <facturic id_user="18446195">
    <artfacturic/>
  </facturic>
  <facturic id_user="18446195">
    <artfacturic/>
  </facturic>
</ROOT>
```